# how to find new coordinates of a line after rotation in android?

Tags: java, android

[Click here to view the image](http://sfour.co.in/doci/Screenshot_1.png)

From the above image how to find (?,?) this coordinate.

I have used this coding in onDraw() method to get the above image.

```
canvas.drawLine(600, 500, 600, 200, paint); //line 1 before rotaion
canvas.rotate(20,600,500);
canvas.drawLine(600, 500, 600, 200, paint); //line 2 after rotation
```

How to get the new coordinates (?,?) as mentioned in the diagram above in android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if A is the angle of rotation then  the coordinates will be :

X coordinate = 600+300*Math.SinA    And
Y coordinate = 500 - 300*Math.cosA

so cordinates = { 600+300*(Math.sin(A) , 500 - 300*(Math.cosA) }

in your case angle is 20 so replace it with A =  Math.toRadians(20)

hope it works :)

Comment: When A as 20, i get x coord as 873 & y coord as 322. Actually i should get x=702,y=218. But when i convert A to Math.toRadians(20), and do that calculation, i get x=702 & y=481. This is what i did.. double angle = Math.toRadians(20);
  double x = 600+300*Math.sin(angle); 
  double y = 200+300*Math.cos(angle);

Comment: X coordinate = (i am getting perfect with that formula). Thank you so much. Y coordinate = i am getting it wrong.

Comment: Math.toRadians  because i think rotation is being done by 20 radians..  okay i have updated the answer ,, it should work now.. :)

Comment: In this line "in your case angle is 20 so replace it with A=20", please replace A=20 with A=Math.toRadians(20).